# How to replace the white spaces and character with specified character in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have a string which is like

```
adgroupname <-"life sciences | medical device"
```

and I want to replace

```
" | " with "|"
```

and the output should be like

```
life sciences|medical device
```

I am using

```
adgroupname <- gsub(pattern=" | ",replacement="|",x=adgroupname)
```

But the output shows up as

```
life|sciences|||medical|device
```

How to do it using R ? new to R.any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe symbol:

```
adgroupname<-gsub(" \\| ", "|", adgroupname)
```

Result:

```
> adgroupname <-"life sciences | medical device" 
> adgroupname
[1] "life sciences | medical device"
> adgroupname<-gsub(" \\| ", "|", adgroupname)
> adgroupname
[1] "life sciences|medical device"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `|` symbol is a special character for regular expressions, and must be escaped.  This symbol means to *or* the two possibilities.  Here, you're saying to replace a space or a space with a `|`.  That is, replace each space with a `|`, which is what it did.

I prefer to use a character class to an escape, which also works:

```
gsub(pattern=" [|] ",replacement="|",x=adgroupname)
## [1] "life sciences|medical device"
```

Same result, but you have fewer backslashes to count.

It's not the case here, but when you must pass the regular expression through a shell to another process, counting the backslashes gets very tedious.

Comment: Also you can use `fixed=TRUE` in the `gsub` argument though most seem to like the pure regex approach.